Units of normalization in the free-particle case
My question starts with the following observation. From the relation
$$\int f(\zeta)\delta(\zeta-a)d\zeta = f(a)$$
it should be clear that the unit of the Dirac delta function $\delta(\zeta-a)$ is the inverse unit of the variable $\zeta$.
In Section 11 of "Quantum Mechanics" (1949) Schiff writes momentum eigenfunctions as
$$u_{\mathbf{k}}=C\exp[i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}]$$
and considers two kinds of normalization. By restricting the domain of the eigenfunctions to a cubic box of sides $L$ and imposing periodic boundary conditions, Schiff concludes that the normalization constant should be $C=L^{-3/2}$. In finite space he chooses $C=(2\pi)^{-3/2}$ which gives the orthonormality relation
$$\int u^{\ast}_{\mathbf{l}}u_{\mathbf{k}}d^3\mathbf{r}=\delta^3(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{l})$$
This is known as k-normalization. In the literature (e.g. Merzbacher) one also finds normalization in terms of momentum or energy. What bothers me is that instead of normalization to dimensionless unity (or whatever number) one has normalization to various units; for instance, in k-normalization $L^3$. How can this seeming arbitrariness be justified ?

The $C=L^{-3/2}$ case is called box normalisation. If you actually go and trace through the entire chain of reasoning, you will realise that the sensible way to define thing in the infinite case (you have a typo as finite) is that it is really $\exp2\pi i\lambda^{-1}x$, where $\lambda$ has the standard interpretation as a wavelength; lengths and reciprocal wavelengths obviously have opposite units, and then no weirdness like needing $C$ to appear will be happening. Instead, weirdness happens in the differential equations, where now $2\pi$ appear.
